# Wxhaskell - wxcore fails due to building phase (g++ error)

Tags: haskell, build, wxwidgets, cabal-install, wxhaskell

I'm trying to build wxhaskell, and it seems there is lots of trouble, I could figure out what to do in some cases, but I'm stuck now.

I'm using wxwidgets-2.8 / wxhaskell-0.11.1.2, and the error that occurs is:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--soname=/home/ming/.cabal/lib/libwxc-gtk2.8.12-0.11.1.2.so’
make: *** [dist/wxc/libwxc-gtk2.8.12-0.11.1.2.so] Fehler 1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wxcore-0.11.1.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The full g++ command is here:

http://pastebin.com/TbrQhWEY

Comment: You should at least show the full g++ command line. Otherwise there is simply not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Your g++ invokation has `-Wl --soname=<something>`. It should be `-Wl,--soname=<something>`

see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).